# Revenue from Admob Ads

Tags: admob, rewardedvideoad

I have looked around the internet but can't find what counts as a click for Admob Ads (Some ad networks count a click as the full ad being watched)

Please could you confirm the following is correct? - please correct me if I am wrong (I likely am)

**Banner Ads** revenue comes if the user clicks the banner ad.

**Interstitial Ads** revenue comes if the user clicks the interstitial or watches the full video to the end (without closing it before the video has played fully).

**Rewarded Ads** revenue comes if the user clicks the rewarded ad or watches the full video to the end (thus getting their reward).

Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of AdMob advertisers pay for clicks. So most of AdMob revenue will be based on clicks.

Comment: Do you have some sources to add for this answer? Are there any documents that go into more detail (e.g. how many advertisers is "Most of")?

Comment: You can add "Bid type" dimension in AdMob network report to see this breakdown: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3436467?hl=en&ref_topic=7383090